# Oval moving program. Oval not moving, anything I can refine here?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I need a little help with my code right here. I followed through the process of creating a keyboard event to move my Oval down if I press arrow key down, move up if I press arrow key up and so on. However, I haven't been able to do so. Is there anything I can refine from my code here? Also planning to implement it too in two buttons, the **Right Translation** and the **Left Translation** buttons here.

Thank you in advance! [Here is the example UI that I've made so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9jnQ.png)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class page309_4 extends JFrame { //implements ActionListener 
    private JButton btnLeftMvmt, btnRightMvmt;
    int oval_x = 150;
    int oval_y = 150;

    public page309_4(){
        setTitle("Oval Mover");
        setSize(600, 150);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel1, panel2;

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel2 = new JPanel();

        panel1.setSize(500,300);
        panel1.add(new MyPanel());
        panel1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
            switch (keycode) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:  oval_y += 10; break; 
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: oval_y -= 10; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: oval_x -= 10; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: oval_x += 10; break;
            }
            }
        });
        panel1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        btnLeftMvmt = new JButton("Left Translation");
        btnRightMvmt = new JButton("Right Translation");
        btnLeftMvmt.addActionListener(bleft -> {


        });
        btnRightMvmt.addActionListener(bright -> {


        });


        panel2.add(btnLeftMvmt);
        panel2.add(btnRightMvmt);


        add(panel1);
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        public MyPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 150));
        }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponents(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED); 
            int oval_x = (getWidth() - 150) / 2;
            int oval_y = (getHeight() - 150) / 2;
            g.fillOval(oval_x, oval_y, 150, 150);
        }
    }   

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        page309_4 f = new page309_4();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't hard-code your oval position

Comment: The coordinates for the oval should be maintained by the `MyPanel` class. Use the [key bindings api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`, it will solve the focus related issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED); 
        int oval_x = (getWidth() - 150) / 2;
        int oval_y = (getHeight() - 150) / 2;
        g.fillOval(oval_x, oval_y, 150, 150);
    }
}
```

The x/y position is defined within the method, so it will never change, not matter what you do.

Having said that, `MyPanel` should be responsible for managing the x/y position directly, this means the `oval_x` and `oval_y` variables should be defined within it.  You should then define functionality which can change those values, for example...

```
  class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private int oval_x = 150;
    private int oval_y = 150;

    public MyPanel() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(600, 150);
    }

    public void moveVerticallyBy(int delta) {
      oval_y += delta;
      repaint();
    }

    public void moveHorizontallyBy(int delta) {
      oval_x += delta;
      repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponents(g);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillOval(oval_x, oval_y, 150, 150);
    }
  }
```

This a basic concept of encapsulation

Next, I would highly recommend using the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` as it will solve the focus related issues.

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Page309_4 extends JFrame { //implements ActionListener 

  private JButton btnLeftMvmt, btnRightMvmt;
  private MyPanel myPanel;

  public Page309_4() {
    setTitle("Oval Mover");
    setSize(600, 150);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel panel1, panel2;

    panel2 = new JPanel();

    myPanel = new MyPanel();
    InputMap im = myPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = myPanel.getActionMap();

    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "Pressed.up");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "Pressed.down");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "Pressed.left");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "Pressed.right");

    am.put("Pressed.up", new VerticalMovementAction(-10, myPanel));
    am.put("Pressed.down", new VerticalMovementAction(10, myPanel));
    am.put("Pressed.left", new HorizontalMovementAction(-10, myPanel));
    am.put("Pressed.right", new HorizontalMovementAction(10, myPanel));

    btnLeftMvmt = new JButton("Left Translation");
    btnRightMvmt = new JButton("Right Translation");
    btnLeftMvmt.addActionListener(bleft -> {

    });
    btnRightMvmt.addActionListener(bright -> {

    });

    panel2.add(btnLeftMvmt);
    panel2.add(btnRightMvmt);

    add(myPanel);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

  }

  public class VerticalMovementAction extends AbstractAction {

    private int delta;
    private MyPanel myPanel;

    public VerticalMovementAction(int delta, MyPanel myPanel) {
      this.delta = delta;
      this.myPanel = myPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      myPanel.moveVerticallyBy(delta);
    }

  }

  public class HorizontalMovementAction extends AbstractAction {

    private int delta;
    private MyPanel myPanel;

    public HorizontalMovementAction(int delta, MyPanel myPanel) {
      this.delta = delta;
      this.myPanel = myPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      myPanel.moveHorizontallyBy(delta);
    }

  }

  class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private int oval_x = (600 - 150) / 2;
    private int oval_y = (300 - 150) / 2;

    public MyPanel() {
      setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(600, 300);
    }

    public void moveVerticallyBy(int delta) {
      oval_y += delta;
      repaint();
    }

    public void moveHorizontallyBy(int delta) {
      oval_x += delta;
      repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponents(g);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillOval(oval_x, oval_y, 150, 150);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Page309_4 f = new Page309_4();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I never knew about the keybinding API because it wasn't being taught at my campus. Once again, thank you very much, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are not repainting panel1 after the keypress, so you'll never see the change. To fix, add panel1.repaint() at the end of the keyPressed() handler.

Comment: Won't make a difference

Comment: This is part of the problem, but there's a lot more changes that are needed to have something that works here.